# 3D input to 2D output in keras functional API

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have three Numpy Arrays each with shape (6000,3,256). I want to use these three as input to Keras Functional API for Dense Neural Network. My output should be of shape (6000,2).
I am confused about how to specify the dimensions.

Comment: what network you want to use?

Comment: dense neural network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dense or Fully Connected layers take 1-d inputs so you need to flatten the input array.

```
X = np.reshape(6000, 3*256)

ip = Input(shape=(3*256))
dense1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(ip)
dense2 = Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')(dense1)
```

You need to choose intermediate layers, loss functions, activations based on your need.